# Need Assistance Interpreting PHP File

Tags: php, interpreter, switch-statement

I have a new project that has a bit of code at the beginning of every page.  I am in need of some clarification on what this series of statements do.  Here is the opening call:

```
<?php
session_start();
$levels = 1;
include("../Connections/main.php");
include("../queries.php");
```

I understand all of it except how `$levels = 1;` relates to `include("../queries.php");`

When I look at `include("../queries.php");`  I see that it begins with the following statement:

```
<?php
switch($levels) {
case 1:
$dir = "../";
break;

case 2:
$dir = "../../";
break;


case 3:
$dir = "../../../";
break;

case 4:
$dir = "../../../../";
break;

case 5:
$dir = "../../../../../";
break;
}
function db_info($table,$where,$value,$info,$dir) {
//the functions just continue from there
```

This is the portion that I don't follow.  I understand that there is a switch statement that offers several cases for `$dir` based upon the value of `$levels` which was defined in the first bit of code.  But how do these different outputs for the `$dir` value translate?  Is this something you've seen or used before?  What does the `../` stand for?  Thanks.

Comment: I understand that you didn't write this code, but the hardcoding of `$dir` levels makes me cringe. You may want to rewrite that entire block as `$dir = str_repeat("../", $levels);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `../` always refers to `parent directory`, the more `../` the more parents you get. With enough you can get to the root of the file system (though you're better off just using `/`). This isn't exactly the best way to accomplish this.

```
$dir = str_repeat( '../', $level );
```

Would be more obvious and it would be more extensible. A better option still would be to have some config file which simply did something like:

```
// obviously this would be a better constant name.
define( 'PATH_TO_STUFF', dirname( __FILE__ ) ); // use __DIR__ on PHP 5.>=3
```

Bonus info:

- `./` = current directory
- `../` = parent directory
- `./../../` = grandparent of current directory
- `./../../foo/../` The parent directory of the folder `foo` in the grandparent directory (ie. the grandparent directory). (I am your father's, brother's, nephew's, cousin's former roommate)
- `/` = file system root directory.

Comment: there are a lot of great answers to this question, but I am awarding it to you for offering the bonus info.  Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

`../` refers to the parent directory of the current directory.

`../../` refers to the parent of the parent. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `../` means previous/parent directory. So if `$level == 1`, then `$dir` will equal `../`.

Something else must use dir to construct a path.